# Make attribute in admin.py "clickable" to edit?

Tags: django, django-admin

So I have something like this in admin.py

```
from .models import Venue
class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["country", "zip", "city", "name", "street"]
admin.site.register(Venue, VenueAdmin)
```

When I'm in the django admin I only have the "land"-value clickable to edit the venue. Is it possible to make also or only "name" clickable?

Thanks in advance and please keep in mind I'm a newbie in case the answer is too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [`list_display_links`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links):

```
class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["country", "zip", "city", "name", "street"]
    list_display_links = ['name', 'country']
```